# Platform defines in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

For my Universal WP8.1/WS8.1 application I need a platform specific code in MainPage.xaml. I have a webView, which should go back when back button clicked, but I don't have a native back button on WS, so how can I make this code work only for WS8.1?

```
<Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0"
  Width="100" Height="70"
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="WebView_GoBack"
  Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle }"
></Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class

```
public class PlatformSpecificFlags
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if on windows store, otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsOnWindowsStore {
        get
        {
#if NETFX_CORE
            return true;
#else
            return false;
#endif
        } }

}
```

You could also define other properties if you like, for other platforms.

In App.xaml you define a resource:

```
<PlatformSpecificFlags x:Key="PlatformSpecificFlags"/>
```

And then use it in xaml like this

```
<Button
  Content="Back"
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  Margin="0,-10,0,0"
  Width="100"
  Height="70"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Click="WebView_GoBack"
  Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle }"
  Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlatformSpecificFlags}, Path=IsOnWindowsStore, Converter={StaticResource BoolToNegateVisibilityConverter}}"></Button>
```